# Using Farseer Physics, how can I get objects to bounce at the correct angle

Tags: physics, monogame, collision-resolution, farseer-physics-engine

I am using the Farseer Physics engine in my MonoGame project. I have static walls which have "body" friction 0 and "body" restitution 1. I have dynamic objects, which are circles, with "body" friction 0 and "body" restitution 1. There is no gravity.

When I launch a dynamic object at a wall, it does not bounce in the way I would expect for a perfectly elastic, frictionless collision. The angle it bounces at should be the reflection (through the wall's normal vector) of the angle it arrives at.

Instead, the dynamic objects often slide *along* the wall:

[image]

In the diagram, the black line is the wall; the blue line is the desired path of the dynamic object; and the orange line is the current path of the dynamic object.

How can I make my dynamic objects bounce properly?

Comment: I haven't used that engine before. But have you tried setting the drag or dampening to 0 on both bodies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Farseer objects can have multiple restitution and friction settings: one set for the body and one set for each fixture.

I was only setting the body settings; adding settings for the fixtures solved the problem:

```
fixture.Restitution = 1f;
fixture.Friction = 0f;
```